# How to use gzipper package in angular 7?

Tags: angular, gzip, angular7

I need to get gzip files, so I tried to use gzipper package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzipper) but have an error 
`bash: gzipper: command not found`
after this:

```
ng build --prod && gzipper ./dist
```

or this command:

```
ng gzipper ./dist
```

I've added command to scripts in package:

```
 "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"gzipper": "gzipper",
```

Can anyone share their experience of using this package?

Comment: What happens if you run `npm run gzipper` from the project root directory?

Comment: yeah, that's was the case, you shoud run it with npm run not ng

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have installed package properly (it will probably be a dev dependency)

```
npm install gzipper --save-dev
npm install --force //just being sure everything is installed
```

Then try to run `npm run gzipper -- --help` with you configuration which you have described above. (make sure your current working directory is the same where package.json is located)

I hope if the output is positive (help displayed) this should get it running in angular as well.

If this dosent work could you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in Github or Stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install using the following command:

> **npm i gzipper -g**

Step 2: Use gzipper with your build commands (e.g. Angular CLI):

> **"scripts": {
>       "build": "ng build && gzipper --verbose ./dist"   }**

Step 3: Build your project

> **ng build --aot**

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the below command

```
npx gzipper compress ./dist
```

Btw you can merge this command with build command as below:

```
 "build-dev": "ng build &&  npx gzipper compress ./dist"
```

So by running this command, every time that you're building your project it'll generate the gzip counterpart of your files

[image]